# Classic ASP error '800a01b6' Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have an error that I cannot resolve, the server is showing this

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'SharedSession'
>
> /includes/minicart.asp, line 183

In minicart.asp we have the following code:

```
(180)dim SharedSession
(181)set SharedSession = Server.CreateObject("SessionMgr.Session2")

(183)dim miniCartXML: miniCartXML = "" & SharedSession("minicart")
```

For some reason when the client clears their browsing history the error goes away but it will eventually come back again.... ??

The server is Windows 2008 r2 64bit. The app is running in IIS7 with 32bit enabled.

Comment: looks like but in SessionMgr ActiveX component. where we could get this ActiveX component?

Comment: This might offer some clues - http://serverfault.com/questions/204591/asp-classic-iis7-issues

Comment: Do you have the source code for `SessionMgr.Session2`?